# How to prevent repeated code in objects that need to wait untill loaded?

Tags: javascript, ajax, structure

Correct me if I'm wrong, but whenever I see redundant blocks of code in my program, I always think there's a better way to think/design it.

Take this out of context example :

```
const ob = new SomeAjaxObject();
ob.on('load', () => {
    doSomeThing(ob); //ob needs to be loaded to call this
})
```

Problem is, if `ob` is already loaded by the time I bind the `load` event, `doSomething` will never trigger.

So, my solution was the following :

```
const ob = new SomeAjaxObject();
if(!ob.loaded){ //This property is synchronous
    ob.on('load', () => {
        doSomething(ob);
    })
}else{
    doSomething(ob);
}
```

Is there a way I can achieve the above without the redundant/repeating code?

Considering I have **no control** over `SomeAjaxObject` soure code

Comment: You could easily put it into a function and then call that function every time you needed something like this, if you wanted.

Comment: Yes but that is just hiding the issue, my question is mostly educational, I know it changes very little.

Comment: Is await and promises what you're looking for? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Answer (score 2):

I can't say with certainty, because I don't know what SomeAjaxObject does, but I would recommend to extend class with your own custom class and try to override onload method.

```
class CustomAjaxObject extends SomeAjaxObject {
    constructor() {
        super()
    }

    onload() {
        doSomething()
    }
}
```

With this method you override parent method, of course I can't say if `SomeAjaxObject` uses internally method `onload` or only `on('load')`. Better try yourself

In case `SomeAjaxObject` calls `onload` method internally, you can simply call your custom class `new CustomAjaxObject()`

Comment: What I was thinking is that, it was whoever design SomeAjaxObject fault for not having a callback as a constructor parameter

Comment: If SomeAjaxObject does async job and onload is called whenever job is done, I would have some worries about your hack code with "ifs".
What if job is done between ```first if``` and ```ob.on('load')``` ?

Comment: Well that would be unfortunate huh

Comment: "Anything that can go wrong will go wrong". E. Murphy :)